# replace first element of nested arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects of arrays... for example:

```
x=[{index:0, data:[{ab: 'c', props: {cde:{efg:'asdf'}, children:"important text" }},"0",34]},
   {index:1, data:[{ab: 'd', props: {cde:{efg:'jkl;'}, children:"some more text" }},"0",35]}]
```

I want to transform what is in data[0] to be what is in data [0].props.children for each element in data.

```
data[*]['data'][0].props.children
```

is there a way to replace what is in data[*]['data'][0] with the text in data[*]['data'][0].props.children.

so the above example would become:

```
x=[{index:0, data:["important text","0",34]},
   {index:1, data:["some more text","0",35]}]
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use map:

```
x = x.map(it => ({
    index: it.index, 
    data: [it.data[0].props.children, it.data[1], it.data[2]]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For each thing in `x`, we want to set `data[0]` to `data[0].props.children`:

```js
const x=[{index:0, data:[{ab: 'c', props: {cde:{efg:'asdf'}, children:"important text" }},"0",34]},
   {index:1, data:[{ab: 'd', props: {cde:{efg:'jkl;'}, children:"some more text" }},"0",35]}];

x.forEach((thing) => {
    thing.data[0] = thing.data[0].props.children;
});

console.log(x);
```

This can be achieved with a regular `for` loop as well:

```
for (const thing of x) {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with forEach and prepare data as per your need as below code it should work for you.

```
x.forEach(item => {
       const [dataObj, dataString, dataNumber] = item.data;
       item.data = [dataObj.props.children, dataString, dataNumber]
   })
```